# Migrating Cake 1.3 to Cake 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, upgrade, cakephp-2.0

I read over the guide here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html which describes the *changes* to Cake for version 2.0, but it doesn't explicitly say **how** to make the upgrade.

I also saw this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html#upgrade-shell which I figured would give a little more instruction.

So far this is what I've done to the existing version (1.3) on my server.

1. Went and grabbed the zipped copy of 2.0 from the repo here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.0
2. Added the new index.php file into my webroot
3. Noticed that the new cake core folder exists one level within the parent directory `lib` so it's `(webroot)/lib/Cake` instead of `(webroot)/cake`. So now in my webroot I have my old '/cake`core, and now a folder called`/lib`which contains the new core (2.0) and my old '/app` folder as well as the old '/vendors` folder.
4. I ran from inside `/lib/Cake/Console` this command: `./Console/cake upgrade all` which scrolled a bunch of stuff like:

   `Done updating`
   `/home/bob_cobb/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuite.php`
5. This didn't change anything in my original /app folder as all controllers are still underscored and lowercase.

What am I missing here? I renamed my old `/cake` core folder and the site stopped working, so it's obviously still relying on that. Should I just scrap everything and start over (delete 1.3 completely while saving all my old files and just re-create them with a fresh version of 2.0)?

Any advice on how to get this migration process going would help greatly. I expect a few things to not work anymore, but I just need a push in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the core one you might need to do more than just run the upgrade shell to make that happen.

I use an enhanced version which should convert everything with a single click.
See "Upgrade using the upgrade shell" @
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/31/freshly-baked-cake2-0-tips/

But most importantly you should always run your scripts from the app dir

```
 app2.0dir>..\lib\Cake\Console\cake Upgrade ...
```

This way it will find the correct paths

Comment: Cool, I've actually been to your site numerous times before. So I guess I'm still trying to understand that the only thing I'm adding to my webroot is the new `/lib` file? Per your instructions on github, it says to put this (your) upgrade shell in `/app/Plugin`... so does this mean that I need to rename my old `/app/plugins` folder to `app/Plugin` and then do this?

Comment: either that or you drop a new "Plugin" folder in for now. If you want to upgrade your other plugins you will need to move them to the "Plugin" folder then, too.

Comment: Still having trouble running the commands: `Upgrade.Upgrade all` In what directory do I use that command? The instructions are a little dry.

Comment: you always navigate to your app dir!